# Nodejs Express not return response on data save in mongo

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple post api which save data in mongoDB issue is my api is stuck on loading and I can see data is saved in MongoDB I can see in console its returning user and not returning that res and stuck on loading but data is saved.

```
  router.post("/register",
        async (req, res) => {
            let user = new User({
                userFullName: req.body.userFullName,
                userEmail: req.body.userEmail,
                userPassword: req.body.userPassword,
                userPhone: req.body.userPhone,
                userGender: req.body.userGender,
                userCountry: req.body.userCountry
            })
            try {
                checkUser = await User.findOne({ userEmail: req.body.userEmail }).exec()
                if (checkUser) {
                    res.status(400).json({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'Email is already in used.'
                    });
                }
    
                else user = await user.save()
                console.log('test')
                console.log(user)
                if (!user) {
                    return res.status(400).send('the user cannot be created!')
                }
                console.log('test2')
                res.status(200).json({ user })
    
            } catch (error) {
    
                // console.log(error); //User profile not found
                // return res.status(404).json({ error }) //return your error msg
    
            }
    
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

document save method doesn't return anything. you shouldn't reassign user document.

```
// user = await user.save() -> this is wrong
 await user.save()
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).send('the user cannot be created!')
        }
    console.log('test2')
    res.status(200).json({ user })
```